# How to mask one raster using another?

Tags: gdal, vrt

I wish to apply one raster (GeoTIFF) as a mask to another raster. How can I do this using GDAL tools? I'd be happy to achieve this as a virtual raster because these images are large.

Will it be necessary to customise a `.vrt` using a text editor, i.e.,  is there no way in `gdalbuildvrt` to insert a `<MaskBand>`? Or is the simplest approach to use `gdal_calc.py` to multiply the rasters together?

Comment: What would be the effect of the mask? Is it that the image that is on the top would hide all pixels of the image that is on the bottom and show them as transparent, or nodata, or with some fixed color?

Comment: @user30184 The mask has values of 1 or zero, and the effect would be the same as multiplication (i.e. overwriting with the implicit nodata fill value of zero).

Comment: Ok, you should explain better in your question that "one raster" is a ready mask with ones and zeroes only.

Comment: Try with two steps: `gdalbuildvrt interim.vrt image1.tif image2.tif` and then `gdal_translate -of VRT -b 1 -mask 2 interim.vrt final.vrt`.